# Precision about method='ffill' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas with first row entirely composed of `NaN` except the first case, which is 0 and I want to fill the `NaN` with `0` by propagating the first case.

I tried this approach but it didn't work, can someone explain me why?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))
d1.iloc[0,1:] = np.nan
print(d1)
d1.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
print(d1)
```

Print of the dataframe before and after `fillna()`

[image: print of the DataFrame before and after fillna()]

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell `fillna()` to fill horizontally:

```
d1 = d1.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
```

It seems that for `axis=1` the `inplace=True` is not implemented. Therefore you have to assign the result back to `d1`.

Comment: im sorry, that don't work. but, i think axis = 1 fill it vertically no ? since axis = 1 is columns